# Using third party libraries inside razor class library

Tags: razor, blazor, sweetalert2

I'm making a proof of concept to have my Blazor components inside a Razor Class Library (RCL) and use them in a web app and a hybrid app on MAUI. It works OK. However, now I'm trying to use Currie Technologies Sweet Alert 2 following the standard implementation procedure: adding the NuGet package to the web project and the RCL project, and registering it in the Program.cs with `builder.Services.AddSweetAlert2();`

I also added the corresponding JS reference on the index.html on the web project

```html
<script src="_content/CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2/sweetAlert2.min.js" defer></script>
```

But when i try to use it i have this error

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2.Fire' ('CurrieTechnologies' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2.Fire' ('CurrieTechnologies' was undefined).

I've used Sweet Alert 2 in other projects without using the RCL, and it works without any problems (I included the corresponding using statement, etc.). Is there anything different in using third-party components from an RCL?